# Passing environment variable to pm2 is not working

Tags: node.js, linux, pm2

I have two API in node js using babel and I have a package.json commands to use to make the application working this is the commands:

```
"build": "del-cli dist/ && babel src -d dist --copy-files",
"serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js",
"start:noupdate": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel-node src/index.js",
"start:serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js",
```

I have two domains one is https://api.website1.com.br and another is https://website2.com.br/api.

They have the same env file name but with another data for each database, that is **.env.production and .env.development**

When I make this "yarn build", my Linux execute this command :

```
"build": "del-cli dist/ && babel src -d dist --copy-files",
```

And this is working fine when I try to put in production mode on my real webservers, i go to the folder from the project and run this command to make the app online with PM2:

```
pm2 start npm -- run-script start:serve NODE_ENV=production
```

That will make this command work:

```
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js"
```

The app runs just fine, but I have a problem he only runs one and doesn't create a new PM2 APP he just restarts what I start.

Example if I go to the folder in my https://api.website1.com.br and run this command first in this he starts, but I go to the another he doesn't start that but reload my already early app don't create a new one, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you please **clearly** state your question?

Comment: In the last line, the command only work for the first app that I use this pm2 start npm -- run-script start:serve NODE_ENV=production, if i go to the folder from the second and use this same command he only restart my earlier app online on PM2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I manage to work this using **pm2 ecosystem**, that I found in this documentation from http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

I configure the default file and put a name my APP:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "app",
    script: "./app.js",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    }
  }]
}
```

and use this command **pm2 start ecosystem.config.js** and now is working, I post here to know if someone has the same problem